# Why was this question closed without explanation?

Tags: discussion

The question I asked here: [Why is SystemModStamp missing updates?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312774/why-is-systemmodstamp-missing-updates) has been closed.  The reason given is "not within this site's scope", but no further explanation is given.

I'd like to know:

1. How this question, about Salesforce integration with other systems (i.e. getting data out of it), is off-topic?
2. Where else this question might be on-topic, if not on this particular site?

The issue I'm trying to solve seems pretty critical to me.  Two columns - *LastModifiedDate* and *SystemModStamp* - appear to not be doing what their names suggest: tracking modifications to records.  There is SF [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336532&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) about these columns, and plenty of other questions ([example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234824/using-systemmodstamp-and-a-timestamp-to-implement-incremental-data-fetch-gotcha?rq=1)) about their intricacies.

If no-one can/wants to answer this question, fair enough.  Closing it, however, seems odd.

Answer (score 2):

I was not a voter on this question, but I suspect that it may have been read too quickly and voters may have misread your question to pertain more to the SQL system you're working on than to Salesforce. I believe that is an incorrect reading and have reopened your on-topic question.

My apologies for the confusion here: you are very welcome to ask about consuming Salesforce APIs and their exact semantics on SFSE, and I'm glad to see you've received an answer and some votes.